# DocuSign embedded signing logout using c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, docusignapi

I have Implemented a code of Embedded Signing Sender View in C# .Net core

```
public string EmbeddedSigning(string accountId, string envelopeId)
{
    try
    {
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        // Start the embedded sending session
        ReturnUrlRequest urlRequest = new ReturnUrlRequest();       
        urlRequest.ReturnUrl = "https://account-d.docusign.com/logout";

        // generate the embedded sending URL
        ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeId, urlRequest);
        
        return  viewUrl.Url;
    }
    catch (DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

After successfully sending the envelope DocuSign page stayed as logged in.
I have tried to logout using ReturnUrl but its not working. Kindly suggest is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

An embedded signer is not "logged in" to DocuSign since an embedded signer does not login.

If you used Authorization Code grant or Implicit grant with your application to obtain an access token, then the person who authenticated is still logged into your application.

To log them out, clear your app's record of the user's access token and (for authorization code grant) the refresh token.